Text from mongodbisn't being displayed to page
I'm making a chat app project and am having problems with displaying the data from my local mongoDB database to the page.
Specifically i'm trying to display the sender, message and timestamp which is nested within another object seen below.
From html
        <% if (chatRoom.chat && chatRoom.chat.length > 0) { %>
            <% chatRoom.chat.forEach(function(chat){ %>
                <ul class="message">
                    <p><%= chat.sender %>:<%= chat.messages %></p>
                    <p><%= chat.timestamp.toLocaleString() %></p>
                </ul>
            <% }) %>
        <% } else { %>
            <p>Chat has no messages</p>
        <% }  %>

Below is what the object/model looks like.
From ChatRoomModelSchema.js
const ChatRoomModal = mongoose.model('ChatRoom', new mongoose.Schema({
    // Define your data schema here
    room: { type: Object, required: true },
    chat: [{
        sender: { type: String, required: true },
        messages: { type: Array, required: true },
        timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }]


The same code works.
The schema and model are working fine.
Data stores successfully.
The template is also working fine.
It shows data correctly.
I am enclosing below the test results using a minimal working example.
Please use it to check it with yours.
For any clarifications, please post your comments.
Tests and Results:
Sample data
test> db.chatrooms.find();
[
  {
    room: { a: 1 },
    chat: [
      {
        sender: 'sender1',
        messages: [ 'Message1' ],
        timestamp: ISODate('2024-06-18T03:02:16.488Z')
      },
      {
        sender: 'sender2',
        messages: [ 'Message2' ],
        timestamp: ISODate('2024-06-18T03:02:16.489Z')
      }
    ],
  }
]

Request URL : http://localhost:3000
Output:
sender1:Message1

6/18/2024, 8:13:33 AM

sender2:Message2

6/18/2024, 8:13:33 AM

server.js
const express = require('express');
const dbsetup = require('./dbsetup');
let docs;

dbsetup()
  .then((newdocs) => {
    docs = newdocs;

    const app = express();

    app.engine('html', require('ejs').__express);
    app.set('views', './');
    app.set('view engine', 'html');

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      console.log(docs);
      res.render('index', { chatRoom: docs });
    });

    app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));
  })
  .catch((error) => {

    process.exit(1);
  });

dbsetup.js
No changes applied in the schema and model
const mongoose = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose');
let ChatRoomModal;

async function run() {

  return mongoose
    .connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test')
    .then(() => {

      ChatRoomModal = mongoose.model(
        'ChatRoom',
        new mongoose.Schema({
          room: { type: Object, required: true },
          chat: [
            {
              sender: { type: String, required: true },
              messages: { type: Array, required: true },
              timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            },
          ],
        })
      );

      return ChatRoomModal.deleteMany({});
    })
    .then(() => {

      return ChatRoomModal.create({
        room: { a: 1 },
        chat: [
          { sender: 'sender1', messages: 'Message1' },
          { sender: 'sender2', messages: 'Message2' },
        ],
      });
    });
}
module.exports = run;

index.html
No changes applied
<% if (chatRoom.chat && chatRoom.chat.length > 0) { %> <%
chatRoom.chat.forEach(function(chat){ %>
<ul class="message">
  <p><%= chat.sender %>:<%= chat.messages %></p>
  <p><%= chat.timestamp.toLocaleString() %></p>
</ul>
<% }) %> <% } else { %>
<p>Chat has no messages</p>
<% } %>

Update : 1st Jul 24
The chatRoom in the below code must be an object.
It should not be an array. However it can contain arrays, for example, the array of chats.
res.render('chatpage', {
  chatRoom: chatRoom,
 …
});

The issue was, the find in the below code returns an array of documents which fails to render.
const chatRoom = await ChatModel.find({}); // by the way, with await, exec is not required.

The solution is findOne which returns a single document or an object.
The filter room must be provided. The below code is the only change required in your code.
const chatRoom = await ChatModel.findOne({ room: { a: 1 } }); // {a : 1} is a test room object as per my db.

Note: If you need to build a list of messages for all rooms, then this solution will not work, because that
requirement bring back the same issue we have been facing so far.
Anyways, please see if that is a need, for any help, please comment on the same question.
Citation:
Working with Embedded JavaScript templating (ejs)

I am also using socketIO would that be the reason why the text isn't being displayed

Please isolate it and test. Please isolate the Express part from SocketIO codes and test to rule out that possibility.

Hi, Is the issue still persisting?

I made an isolated version just using express, messages get added to the database but still don't display on screen

Thank you for your update and appreciate your efforts. Please show me the new code, shall look into it. if you have git account, and if you will, please share through it. Or share only the highlights of the new codes by amending your question, that way also it is fine.

Here is the version without socket IO : https://github.com/MortalChris/Messaging-App/tree/testing-if-socket-io-is-the-problem

Hi, Thank you for the source code. There was a very minor issue and a fix has been proposed for it. Please see the same answer, "section Update 1st Jul 24".

Sorry , but what do you mean by "section Update 1st Jul 24"

Sorry for the confusion caused by me. Please go through my previous answer. I have appended some information to it. It is at the end. To identify this information, there is a section name given to it as "Update 1st Jul 24". This section explains the issue and the fix which could be done by using the source code you shared with me. The summary is that the issue has been fixed.
